# How to simply display application when you open a Push Notifications with PARSE?

Tags: android, android-activity, parse-platform, push-notification

By default if I "click" on a push notification generated by Parse.com, it opens my application REFRESHING the activity (so if I was logged in a page, I will be redirected at the login page).

What I need is that when I "click" on a push notification, it just open up my application without refreshing it... just displaying it on the front. (so that if I was logged in a page, I will be still logged in)

How can I do that? I've read that there is this class called ParsePushBroadcastReceiver which has a method called ACTION_PUSH_OPEN, but I don't really understand how to do what I need to.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: post the code of the activity which you want to get opened without refreshing it when you receive notification.

Comment: it's my mainActivity ! and it is 650 lines of code :D

Comment: Awesome :P, now just put a boolean variable in your onCreate() method and check whether it is called by notification or newly created.